# Variables outside of an if statement in discord.js

Tags: javascript, scope, discord.js

I need to use certain variables to have a value only if it is triggered, but I need to use those variables outside the `if` statement. Does anyone know how to do this?

Code:

```
      let commandRan = false
      let User = msg.author.id
      if (msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("pe!command")){
        msg.channel.send('Hello! say 1 or 2');
        commandRan = true
        User = msg.author.id
      };
      
        if (msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("1")){
                  if (commandRan === true) {
                    if (User === msg.author.id){ 
                      msg.channel.send("1!")
                    }
                  }
              } else if (msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("2")){         
                    msg.channel.send("2!")
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the variable outside the if method and affect it's value inside:

```
let v1; //this is the var declaration.
//your code

if(<some condition>){
  v1 = "something";
}
//more code
if (v1 !== undefined){
  console.log(v1);
//whatever you want to do in this case    
}
```

Note that undefined is a reserved keyword

More info can be found here [in the mozilla fondation docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)